# Efficiently storing small, fixed-length arrays in an SQL database

Tags: database, database-design

I hope someone more experienced in databases can advise me.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to store a 5-length array of 1-bit values. This gives only 32 distinct combinations.

If I store it in 5 columns, it will take 5 bytes per user. This "feels bad" given that it's only 5 bits of data - and 35 wasted bits.

Another option is to use a lookup table and store a single byte reference into it for each user. This "feels bad" as it will make queries unnecessarily complex and slower.

The only other option I can think of is to serialize the values, which then requires overhead for every operation and breaks the rule of first normal order.

Or, maybe there's a better database I should be using that allows finer grain control over the sizes of INTEGER that will be stored in it? I'm currently using SQLite.

P.S. - This is one example, but I actually have numerous other similar arrays to store, so it's not quite as simple as sucking up the 35 wasted bits per user.

Comment: If your database allows a bit type, use it, otherwise consider a set of five bool values.  Frankly you're wasting your time optimizing at this level.

Comment: _"If I store it in 5 columns, it will take 5 bytes per user."_ - this is DBMS specific. For example MS SQL Server would store that in 1 byte (5 bits + "slack"), while Oracle would indeed use byte per bit (but you can use [RAW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT613) to implement this bit-field manually). In any case, breaking the 1st normal form should be your first concern, before considering storage cost.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to understand this, you will have to refresh yourself on the Binary representation of Decimal numbers as well as Bit-Wise Operators and Bit Shifting.  Each particular Programming language has different Operators for "Bitwise AND" and "Bit Shifting".  Please refer to your programming Language you are using for the Proper Bit Operators.  The "Bitwise AND" Operator allows you to find out whether a certain bit position is 1 or 0 by doing a Logical Binary AND operation on each bit.
>
> SQLite Datatypes documented here http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html support the following "dynamic types"

1. NULL - The Value is NULL
2. INTEGER - The value is signed integer, stored in 1,2,3,4,6,8 bytes depending on value
3. REAL - The value is a floating point as 8 byte IEEE floating point number
4. TEXT - The value is a text string
5. BLOB - The value is a blob of data

> Everything on a computer is merely a series of Binary 1's and 0's, with usually the smallest allocation being 8-bit equals 1 byte.  How you interpret those 1's and 0's is really up to you.  So 8-bits can be an INTEGER if you want it to be or it can be a CHARACTER or anything really...  Below I will propose the way you can store your 5-bits into 1 byte and interpret it as 5 values with either 1 or 0 as the value, or an X number of bits as you stated which can be "on" or "off" in the most minimal Allocation size as possible.
>
> In your situation where you are using just 5 bits and yet want to Minimize storage requirements, you can store it as a 1 byte (8-bit) Integer value (this is the smallest data structure SQLite allows, it does not have a Bit DataType) and then use a "bit mask" or combination of "shifting bits" to retrieve the values of each of the 5 positions or using the "bit-wise AND" operation.  For example, you can represent your 5-bit structure (length 5 array of 1-bit each) with 3 leading zeros with the 5 right-most bits having meaning (3 bits + 5 bits = 8 bits = 1 byte).  Such as 00011111, 00010101, 00010000... (notice leading left most 3 bits are Zeros).
>
> Keep in mind a 1 byte (8-bit) Integer is 11111111 in Binary or 255 Decimal.  In some languages this is referred to as a TinyInt or SmallInt.  In your case if you only use the Lower 5 bits, then your remaining upper 3 bits should always be 000.
>
> As an example, if my value was 00011111 Binary which equals 31 Decimal.  So if I wanted to know the first bit value I would "bitwise AND" it with 00000001, and if I wanted to know the 2nd position I would bitwise AND with 00000010, 3rd position would be 00000100, 4th position 00001000, and 5th 00010000.  These specific Binary Values representing each Position is called a "Bit-Mask".
>
> The way the "Bitwise AND" Operator works, is if I have a value, and I "BitWise AND" it with the proper position "Bitmask" and it equals that "BitMask" Value, then that Bit was set.  For example if my Value is 00010010 Binary (18 Decimal) and I want to find out if the 2nd positional bit is Set (that is equal to 1) then I use BitMask 00000010.  If 00010010 "BitWise AND" with 00000010 = 00000010 then the 2nd bit is set, if not it is not set.  And if I want to find if the 5th positional bit is set, then I would do 00010010 "Bitwise AND" with 00010000, if it equals 00010000 then the 5th bit is set (that is the 5th bit equals 1), otherwise the 5th bit was not set (meaning 5th bit was 0).

Keep in mind, I am explaining this in Binary, but the datatype is an Integer, so visually in the SQLite DB you will see it as a Decimal value, but since everything on a computer is just a stream of Bits, you will be Operating on that Datatype using Bit Operation.